# double.Epsilon vs. std::numeric_limits<double>::min()

Tags: .net, c++, floating-point

Why `double.Epsilon != std::numeric_limits<double>::min()`?

On my PC:
`double.Epsilon == 4.9406564584124654E-324` and is defined in .NET
`std::numeric_limits<double>::min() == 2.2250738585072014e-308`

Is there a way to get 2.2250738585072014e-308 from .NET?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're different because [`double.Epsilon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon.aspx) returns the smallest *representable* value. [`numeric_limits<double>::min()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69bwfeks.aspx) returns the smallest *normalized* value.

Basically `double.Epsilon` is the equivalent to `numeric_limits<double>::denorm_min()`.

The easiest way of getting the equivalent in .NET is probably to work out the bit pattern for the minimal normalized number and use [`BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.int64bitstodouble.aspx).

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.
Thanks Jon

Comment: As this question is also tagged C++, I'll note that in C++ std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon represents the *normalized min*, based on the docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon

*"Epsilon is the difference between 1.0 and the next value representable by the floating-point type T"* which cannot be subnormal.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use C++/CLI to return the value:

```
double epsilon() { return std::numeric_limits<double>::min(); }
```

Why would you want to though? Why do they have to be the same? You should try to avoid skating on the edges of your floating point numbers.

Answer (score -2):

Epsilon is the minimal possible difference between two doubles. (Edit: not exact, it's the minimal positive nonzero number in this case).

```
double.MinValue
```

is what you need.

Comment: The OP is looking for a tiny but positive number. double.MinValue is a massive and negative number.

Comment: Uh? I thought, tnat numeric_limits returns minimal value that can be represented, not minimal nonzero number..

Comment: Take a look at the values given in the question: "std::numeric_limits<double>::min() == 2.2250738585072014e-308"